# Count(*) (asterisk) on Querydsl / MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, querydsl

The original functional MySQL query that lists all and only the providers that have all the listed tags:

```
SELECT * FROM provider
  INNER JOIN provider_tag
  ON provider_tag.provider_id = provider.id AND provider_tag.tag_id in (1, 2)
  GROUP BY (provider.id)
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Translating to MySQLQuery in Querydsl is straightforward...

```
MySQLQuery query = new MySQLQuery(conn, dialect);

List<Integer> tagIds = ...;

query.from(provider)
    .innerJoin(provider_tag)
    .on(providerTag.providerId.eq(provider.id), providerTag.tagId.in(tagIds))
    .groupBy(provider.id)
    .having(???);
```

... except for the condition in `having`.

How do I add `COUNT(*)` to the query?

**EDIT after Timo's 1st correction proposal**:

So, the query looks like this:

```
SearchResults<Tuple> result = query.from(provider)
    .innerJoin(providerTag)
    .on(providerTag.providerId.eq(provider.id), providerTag.tagId.in(tagIds))
    .groupBy(provider.id)
    .having(Wildcard.count.eq((long) tagIds.size()))
    .listResults(
        provider.id,
        provider.name);
```

However, this causes an SQLException `Illegal operation on empty result set`, if the result set is empty.

My other queries that return an empty result set do not cause exceptions, so I guess I should not need to catch the exception, but there is a problem that should be fixed?

The generated MySQL works perfectly (returns 0 rows), so the problem is not there.

**EDIT 2**:

The problem was in `groupBy()`. This seems to work, if one applies the correction shown in the [issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1055).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The querydsl equivalent for `COUNT(*)` is `Wildcard.count`.

Comment: I am getting exceptions for empty result sets, see the edit in the original question.